# spry menu take up whole height of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having trouble getting my side spry menu to take up the length of the whole web page. I was thinking some like this

```
    $("nav").css({
    "height" : $("nav").height()
    });
```

would maybe suffice in stretching out the side, but still no luck. I just want grey like in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLq9b/1/ to reach the bottom of the page regardless of the length.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
nav {
    background: #666;
    padding-top: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

no jQuery needed.